# List private IP addresses of EC2 instances of particular project in OEC

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I want to list all the Private IP address of my EC2 instances of particular project in OEC using AWS CLI, what AWS CLI command i can use to get this info?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your project information is kept in a Tag on the Amazon EC2 instance, you would use:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --filters Name=tag:Project,Values=OEC --query Reservations[].Instances[].PrivateIpAddress --output text
```

Tags are case-sensitive.